# Hadoop streaming with two -inputFormat's?

Tags: hadoop, streaming, mapreduce

Suppose I have two files I want to Map through in different formats.. One is a sequence file and the other is plaintext.  Is there a way to specify an `-inputFormat` for each one respectively?  Or is there something else I should be doing to map through both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the MultipleInputs class is for. For each input you make a call to MultipleInputs:

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, inputPath, inputFormatClass, mapperClass);
```